Finding a general solution to the SDE $dX_t = (\mu_1 (t) X_t + \mu_2 (t)) dt + \sigma (t) dB_t$
I am looking to find a general solution to the stochastic differential equation: $$dX_t = (\mu_1 (t) X_t + \mu_2 (t)) dt + \sigma (t) dB_t \tag{1}$$
I am happy to assume any regularity conditions needed for $\mu_1, \mu_2,$ and $\sigma$ in order for any integrals that appear to exist.
I attempted this problem by applying integration by parts to $Y_t$ where:
$$Y_t = X_t e^{ - \int_0^t \mu_1 (s) ds}$$
This led to the result:
$$ d(Y_t) = X_t  d(e^{- \int _0^t \mu_1(s) ds}) + e^{- \int _0^t \mu_1 (s)ds} dX_t + (dX_t)(d(e^{- \int _0^t \mu_1(s) ds})) \tag{2}$$
However, before proceeding, I am concerned that I am going down the wrong path with this problem as the additional factor of $X_t$ in the solution which seems non-trivial to eliminate may pose problems in finding an explicit solution for $X_t$.
Is my above approach workable and if so, how should I proceed? If not, what would a better approach to solve this SDE be?

Relevant excerpt from duplicate answer:

$$\mathrm{d}Z_t = -a(t)Z_t\mathrm{d}t, \ \quad Z_0 =1 $$
and so
$$Z_t = \exp\left( -\int_0^t a(s)\mathrm{d}s\right).$$
Therefore,
\begin{align*}\mathrm{d}(X_tZ_t) =& Z_tb(t)\mathrm{d}t+ Z_t h(t)\mathrm{d}B_t
\\ X_tZ_t =& X_0 + \int_0^t Z_sb(s) \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t Z_s h(s) \mathrm{d}B_s\\
X_t = & X_0Z_t^{-1}+ Z_t^{-1}\left( \int_0^t Z_sb(s) \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t Z_s h(s) \mathrm{d}B_s\right) \\
X_t = & X_0 e^{ \int_0^t a(s)\mathrm{d}s}\\ &+ e^{ \int_0^t a(s)\mathrm{d}s}\left( \int_0^t e^{ -\int_0^s a(r)\mathrm{d}r}b(s) \mathrm{d}s + \int_0^t e^{ -\int_0^s a(r)\mathrm{d}r}h(s) \mathrm{d}B_s\right).
\end{align*}

